# NestJS EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "Repository" was found

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I understand there are many posts about this topic. I am really struggling to understand what in the heck I am attempting to do to resolve the issue. Using Postman, when I attempt to hit a route, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] No metadata for "OrganizationsRepository" was found.
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "OrganizationsRepository" was found.
```

Here is what my code looks like

```
// app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      database: 'my-database',
      username: 'postgres',
      password: 'password',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    OrganizationsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
// organizations.repository.ts

@EntityRepository(Organization). // this is showing as deprecated
export class OrganizationsRepository extends Repository<Organization> {
...
}
```

```
// organization.entity.ts

@Entity({ name: 'organizations' })
export class Organization extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;
...
```

I believe I need to create a new `DataSource` -- or more specifically, a custom repository?

I've always used the above to read from my database without issue. Now all of the sudden I am getting this error and I'm not sure how to resolve within the code I have.

Comment: are you planning to use typeorm v0.3? then you need to get ride of that `@EntityRepository` as it won't be available in the next release of typeorm. I guess if you downgrade your typeorm version to `0.2` and `@nestjs/typeorm` to 8.0.4, it will work

Comment: Yeah, I should try to keep current. Right now I have `"typeorm": "^0.3.6"` in my `package.json` file. What I am most confused about is how to replace it. I've tried creating the `dataSource` in my `app.module` file, but I am not sure how to actually use it.

Comment: read the release notes of 0.3: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases/tag/0.3.0 and this gist: https://gist.github.com/anchan828/9e569f076e7bc18daf21c652f7c3d012

Comment: I am most confused here (example repositor): `export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User)` where does `dataSource` come from?

Comment: I guess it's an instance of `DataSource` https://typeorm.io/multiple-data-sources

Answer (score 9):

EntityRepository is deprecated so you can replace it with Injectable() then you need to modify your repository, module and  service. I gave you example for you, I hope it helps.

repository.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Organization } from './Organization.entity';
 
@Injectable() // here
export class OrganizationRepository extends Repository<Organization> {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(Organization, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }

        sync createOrganization({ title, description }: CreateOrganizationDto):Promise<Organization> {...}
  }
```

Organization.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Organization } from './Organization.entity';
import { OrganizationController } from './Organization.controller';
import { OrganizationRepository } from './Organization.repository';
import { OrganizationService } from './Organization.service';
 
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Organization])],
  controllers: [OrganizationController],
  providers: [OrganizationService, OrganizationRepository],
})
export class OrganizationModule {}
```

Organization.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OrganizationRepository } from './organization.repository';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Organization } from './organization.entity';
 
@Injectable()
export class OrganizationService {
  constructor(private readonly OrganizationRepository: OrganizationRepository) {}
 
  async getOrganizationById(id: string): Promise<Organization> {
    const record = this.OrganizationRepository.findOne({ where: { id } });
    if (!record) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return record;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been on a merry go round with this issue - thanks to following old tutorial with the deprecated `@EntityRepository`. Thanks @het